# How to convert country name into currency code?

Tags: java, android

Suppose  I  have  country name as  USA  .So  I  want to convert  to  USD.I  have  only  country name  from   webservice.

I  have  tried  this code  but  how to  convert country name  into  Locale object.  Can  anybody suggest in  this  problem?

```
String countryName=jsonObject.getString("country");
```

Comment: Locale takes a language code as a parameter to constructor, not country name: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#Locale(java.lang.String)

Comment: Just pointing out the problem in your code - why would you expect it to work since it's clearly documented that it wont?

Comment: ok  now  tell how  to  solve

Comment: I found an answer for the similar problem. Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27228664/5167580

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-i18n library this is specifically designed for this purpose.

From its GitHub page,

> Package to support internationalization, containing ISO 3166-1 country
>   code enum, ISO 639-1 language code enum, etc.

Example specific to this question

```
String countryName = jsonObject.getString("country");
List<CurrencyCode> codes = CurrencyCode.getByCountry(countryName, false)
```

Simple example to see available list (from Github page),

```
// List all the currency codes.
for (CurrencyCode code : CurrencyCode.values())
{
    System.out.format("[%s] %03d %s\n", code, code.getNumeric(), code.getName());
}

// List all the country codes.
for (CountryCode code : CountryCode.values())
{
    System.out.format("[%s] %s\n", code, code.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Provide country code instead of country name

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
Map<String, String> countries = new HashMap<>();
for (String iso : Locale.getISOCountries()) {
    Locale l = new Locale("", iso);
    countries.put(l.getDisplayCountry(), iso);
}

System.out.println(countries.get("Switzerland"));
System.out.println(countries.get("Andorra"));
System.out.println(countries.get("Japan"));
 }
```

Comment: Its useful answer